# Slicing behavior of python range()[:]

Tags: python, python-3.x, slice

I came across an interesting bit of code in a QC review and was surprised by its behavior. I am curious if it is documented anywhere.

```
for i in range(0, my_array.max(), 3)[:]:
    # other code here
```

I was curious about the need for the `[:]` after `range`, so I tested it:

```
>>> range(0, 10, 3)
range(0, 10, 3)
>>> range(0, 10, 3)[:]
range(0, 12, 3)
```

The actual sequence defined by these ranges is identical, but I do not see this slicing behavior documented anywhere in the Python [range](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#ranges) documentation, so I was curious what is actually going on here.

Comment: As long as it produces the correct result, it can do it however it wants.

Comment: I don't see the point of the slice in the original `for` loop. Slicing is only needed if you need to make independent copies of the range.

Comment: this is the source (i guess): https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/rangeobject.c#L298

Comment: did you ask the author why he used the slicing in this point? makes no sense for me

Comment: it's some sort of rounding to next multiple of step:
>>> range(0, 14, 3)[:]
range(0, 15, 3)
>>> range(0, 99, 10)[:]
range(0, 100, 10)

Answer (score 4):

For a moment let's pretend that `range` still returned a `list`. Slicing the `range` object returns a `range` object which would act as if you were slicing the underlying list. Instead of doing this with a list though, the `range` object is able to take care of it in constant time using arithmetic.

```
>>> range(0, 90, 2)[10:23]
range(20, 46, 2)

>>> list(range(0, 90, 2)[10:23])
[20, 22, 24, 26, 28, 30, 32, 34, 36, 38, 40, 42, 44]
```

When you do something like:

```
range(0, 10, 3)[:]
```

Python slices it with arithmetic.

My assumption is that when determining the final element it rounds up. It tries to compute the zeroth element in the range to start with. This will be `start + step * 0 = 0`.

Then Python tries to get the ending element. There are `(10 - 0) // 3 + 1 = 4` elements in the range, so the ending element is `start + step * n_elements = 0 + 3 * 4 = 12`.

Answer (score 1):

I think a few things are mixed here.

- `range` produces slicing behavior, because slicing with non-default indexes makes sense:

```py
>>> list(range(10, 20)[3:7])
[13, 14, 15, 16]
```

- There is an idiom of copying a list (which is mutable) by producing a slice with all default indexes: `some_list[:]` is equivalent to something like `[x for x in some_list]`.
- There is the strange code that does `[:]` for the range object (or the actual list, if it's Python 2) which makes *no* sense. The generated range object / list is not referenced anywhere else anyway.
- Python documentation lists slicing among ["Common Sequence Operations"](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#common-sequence-operations) in a chapter named "Sequence Types — `list`, `tuple`, *`range`*" (emph. mine). So it's documented, but few people ever read it.